# Run commands with a loop variable in parallel, at most N at the same time

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, wget

I have three thousand files on a server. I can retrieve one at a time via a REST API call. I have written a command to retrieve these files. It works perfectly, but for my login timing out after roughly 200 downloads.

I would like to download all of these files in parallel rather than serially. Ideally, I would like to retrieve files 1-200 at once, 200-400 at the same time, 400-600 at the same time....etc.

So my attempt :

```
FOR /L %i in (0,1,200) do wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition  --load-cookies cookies.txt \ -p https://username:password@website.APICall.com/download/%i
```

How can I convert this into the parallel call I want to create?

Thanks.

Comment: The Windows part might make everything a bit tricky, GNU parallel might do the trick for you: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Answer (score 3):

With Cygwin and GNU Parallel installed you can download the 3000 files with 200 parallel downloads running constantly using:

```
seq 3000 | parallel -j 200 wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition  --load-cookies cookies.txt -p https://username:password@website.APICall.com/download/{}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this suggestion. What do the curly braces represent here? Thanks.

Comment: The {} is GNU Parallel's default substitution string - similar to your %i .

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I thought this was the case, was just hoping for clarification. Appreciate it. You may be able to provide some insight for this related question also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942855/wget-ignoring-content-disposition . Thank you very much :).

Comment: @Adrian None that I know of, but this will install it if you have gpg, wget, perl, and make: (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I doubt your command works, because the iterator variable needs a double percent as far as I know, i.e. `%i` needs to be `%%i`.</strike>

Concerning the parallelization, you can try this:

```
FOR /L %%i IN (0,1,200) DO ( 
    start wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition --load-cookies cookies.txt -p "https://username:password@website.APICall.com/download/%%i"
)
```

It will, for your first 200 downloads, spawn a seperate process (and shell window!) for every download. Doing so will cause a lot of load on the server and I'm not sure this is really the way to go forward. But it does what you've asked for.

Edit: *The above note holds for using the command in a `.bat` file, if you're executing this on the shell directly, a single percent is sufficient.*

Answer (score 0):

Don't go through the hassle of Cygwin; trying to turn Windows into UNIX is compounding problems and adds layers of dependencies. Use PowerShell.

If you can get 200 files downloaded before timing out, break it up into three jobs:

```
invoke-command -asjob -scriptblock {$files = @(1..200);$files | foreach-object{ & wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition  --load-cookies cookies.txt -p https://username:password@website.APICall.com/download/$_}};
invoke-command -asjob -scriptblock {$files = @(201..400);$files | foreach-object{ & wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition  --load-cookies cookies.txt -p https://username:password@website.APICall.com/download/$_}};
invoke-command -asjob -scriptblock {$files = @(601..400);$files | foreach-object{ & wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition  --load-cookies cookies.txt -p https://username:password@website.APICall.com/download/$_}};
```

Or get [Invoke-Parallel](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Run-Parallel-Parallel-377fd430) and use it like this:

```
$filenames = @(1..600);    
invoke-parallel -InputObject $servers -throttle 200 -runspaceTimeout 30 -ScriptBlock { & wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition  --load-cookies cookies.txt -p https://username:password@website.APICall.com/download/$_}
```

Another (and probably the best) option would be to use [invoke-webrequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx), but I don't know if it will work with your cookie requirement here.

Disclaimer: working from memory as I don't have Windows or your URL accessible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative [to the GNU `parallel` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29876479/648265) is the good ol' `xargs` with the `-P` option:

```
$ seq 3000 | xargs -i '{}' -n 1 -P 200 wget <url_start>{}<url_end>
```