# WGET ignoring --content-disposition?

Tags: bash, cygwin, wget, seq, gnu-parallel

I am trying to run a command to download 3000 files in parallel. I am using Cygwin + Windows.

Downloading a single file via WGET in terminal :

```
wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition --load-cookies cookies.txt \ -p https://username:password@website.webpage.com/folder/document/download/1?type=file
```

allows me to download the file with ID 1 singularly, in the correct format (as long as `--content-disposition` is in the command).

I iterate over this REST API call to download the entire folder (3000 files). This works OK, but is quite slow.

```
FOR /L %i in (0,1,3000) do wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition  --load-cookies cookies.txt \ -p https://username:password@website.webpage.com/folder/document/download/%i?type=file
```

Now I am trying to run the program in Cygwin, in parallel.

```
seq 3000 | parallel -j 200 wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition  --load-cookies cookies.txt -p https://username:password@website.webpage.com/folder/document/download/{}?type=file
```

It runs, but the file-name and format is lost (instead of `"index.html"`, for example, we may get `"4@type=file"` as the file-name).

Is there a way for me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you would like them named. Let us assume you want them named: index.[1-3000].html

```
seq 3000 | parallel -j 200 wget -O index.{}.html --no-check-certificate --content-disposition  --load-cookies cookies.txt -p https://username:password@website.webpage.com/folder/document/download/{}?type=file
```

My guess is that it is caused by --content-disposition being experimental, and the `wget` used by CygWin may be older than the `wget` used by the FOR loop. To check that run:

```
wget --version
```

in CygWin and outside CygWin (ie. where you would run the FOR loop).